# Make Laravel / PHPUnit remember all requests done

Tags: php, laravel, api, phpunit

I use Laravel and PHPUnit. In my tests, I have a lot of requests which tend to test my REST-like API, and it's doing the job quite nicely. Now I wonder if I could use all those tests to make some description/documentation for my API.

Formally, how can I log/access all requests and responses created by `$this->get(...)`, `$this->post(...)` and so on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well depending on how you write your test name you can use the options on PHPUnit cli. You can read more about them [here](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/textui.html#textui.clioptions).

> --testdox-html        Write agile documentation in HTML format
>   to file.
>   --testdox-text        Write agile documentation in
>   Text format to file.

When you run your tests, instead of just running:

```
phpunit
```

try:

```
phpunit --testdox-html documentation.html
```

A little more detailed [description](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/other-uses-for-tests.html):

> PHPUnit's TestDox functionality looks at a test class and all the test
>   method names and converts them from camel case PHP names to sentences:
>   testBalanceIsInitiallyZero() becomes "Balance is initially zero". If
>   there are several test methods whose names only differ in a suffix of
>   one or more digits, such as testBalanceCannotBecomeNegative() and
>   testBalanceCannotBecomeNegative2(), the sentence "Balance cannot
>   become negative" will appear only once, assuming that all of these
>   tests succeed.

The output will look as follows:

```
phpunit --testdox BankAccountTest
PHPUnit 6.1.0 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

BankAccount
 [x] Balance is initially zero
 [x] Balance cannot become negative
```

**Update**

As far as logging all requests, the only thing that comes to mind is to extend test case. I tried it out myself in a simple form and it seemed to work:

```
abstract class TestCase extends Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase
{

    public function get($uri, array $headers = [])
    {
        parent::get($uri, $headers);
        $txt = "GET REQUEST: ".$uri." HEADERS: ".json_encode($headers)."\n";
        file_put_contents('logs.txt', $txt.PHP_EOL , FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
    }

}
```

Comment: Oh, I see, that's awesome, but it only tells something about my tests. I mean, but I'd like to remember all query strings sent by GET requests to my application, and all post data sent with other methods, and responses for them

Comment: Ah interesting, I'm not so sure if there is anyway to achieve that easily but I will see if I can dig anything up.

Comment: @Alagunto I've updated with a possible solution, would require a little bit of work but might be worth trying.

Comment: Mhm, nice idea! I'll wait if someone can find something more tricky. If not, I'll accept this one